# How to forward external api errors through WebClient in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a controller that forwards content from an external api through a GET request.

Question: how can I also expose the original external response in case of exceptions (means: forward the statuscode, response body, and also content type).

```
@RestController
public class ProxyController {
    @Autowired
    private WebClient client;

    @GetMapping(value = "/proxy", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Object> proxy() {
        return client.get().uri("external/api")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Object.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to deserialize the error response first and then include required details into the result exception

```
webClient.get().uri("external/api")
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response ->
                response.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class)
                        .flatMap(errorResponse ->
                                response.createException()
                                        .flatMap(ex -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorResponse.getDetails(), ex)))
                        )
        )
        .bodyToMono(Object.class);
```

You could also use custom expection instead of `RuntimeException` to include more details and handle it doownstream.